# fdisk shows "No free sectors available" while there is enough space

Tags: linux, fdisk

I have a 3.5T ssd, and I have made a 1.5T partition in it before. Then I want to add another partition. But it always shows there is no free sectors left which I think is pretty weird.

```
# fdisk /dev/nvme0n1 

WARNING: The size of this disk is 3.8 TB (3840000000512 bytes).
DOS partition table format can not be used on drives for volumes
larger than (2199023255040 bytes) for 512-byte sectors. Use parted(1) and GUID 
partition table format (GPT).

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.23.2).

Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 3840.0 GB, 3840000000512 bytes, 7500000001 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

        Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/nvme0n1p1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT

Command (m for help): n
Partition type:
   p   primary (1 primary, 0 extended, 3 free)
   e   extended
Select (default p): e
Partition number (2-4, default 2): 
No free sectors available

Command (m for help):
```

Comment: Why not heed warning and change from mbr partition table to gpt? ( For which gdisk better than fdisk BTW)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems here: your version of `fdisk` apparently doesn’t support GUID partition tables (GPT), which your disk is using, and your disk is too big for MBR-based partitioning.

The reason you can’t create a new partition is that `fdisk` is seeing the protective MBR, which is set up on GPT for exactly this scenario: to prevent MBR-based tools from messing things up on a GPT layout. `fdisk` sees a single partition occupying all the space it can access.

You need to use a GPT-compatible tool such as `parted`, or `gparted` if you have a GUI, or `gdisk`, or a GPT-compatible `fdisk`.